# the neural networks are too sensitive for the input

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I have the following two feature vectors:

```
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
    0.2567    0.2567
    0.0105    0.0105
    0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000    0.0000
    0.0000    0.0000
```

let we call the first one `A` , and the second one`B`. `A` have used in learning a Neural networks, which is gives you the following output if you apply it again to the NN:

```
 1.0000
    0.0000
   -0.0000
```

But if you apply the feature vector `B`, the following output will give :

```
-0.2475
    1.0524
    0.5106
```

How the results get differ with this form! the feature vectors are the same (except at zeros, there are difference in the signs of zeros)

Comment: Zeroes don't have sign. If they do, that means you have some very small non zero numbers and you just don't see the rest of the number.

Comment: @DenisTarasov Yes, but I assumed the reader know what the "sign" of zeros mean

Comment: Ok, I see, just wanted to clarify things. So what you are asking about? Do you want to know, how NN can compute such different outputs, or how they can be trained to produce such result or how to get rid of this situation?

Comment: @DenisTarasov, As you see the two feature vectors are approximately the same, But the two outputs are completely different. It should be there a "region of play" where the values of the same class can differe from each other, but the classification algorithm can detect them, In my case if the feature vector   differ with .00005, it will cause the neural network to change it's output completely !

Comment: @user3840877 Why not? You know what a (good) hash function does? 1 changed bit in the input gives a completely new output. It's nothing unthinkable. Sadly you haven't told us why you think the output should be similar as well. Try to give more details in your question next time

Comment: @runDOSrun, I don't know if you see the previous command or not, however,Assume that we have NN, which has 2 input, and the feature vector [2,2] represent class 1,  So if you apply the feature vector [2.00001 2.000001] what you expect that NN classify this?

Comment: @user3840877 You need to tell us more. Number of epochs, learning rate, architecture. What is your training set? An answer depends on all of these factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any model can act like that on those two instances. Your question is very broad, so I'll just list a few things that you should consider.

1. **Data normalization and scaling**

You might have better luck by applying [feature scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling) or [mean normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29) to your data.

2. **Detect overfitting**

Use a method of [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) (10 fold cross validation is often used) to detect if you are overfitting: if the accuracy on your training folds are much higher than those on your test folds, then you are overfitting your training data.

Cross validation can also be used to tweak the parameters of your model for best performance: just rerun the cross validation process after every tweak.

3. **Solve overfitting**

Using regularization usually solves overfitting issues. There are a number of methods you can use for regularization, so you should do some searching.

Getting more data is unlikely to properly solve the problem, and is usually not worth the time. Do it if you can, but it's not a silver bullet that you can rely on to fix overfitting issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to this very good paper [SENSITIVITY AND GENERALIZATION
IN NEURAL NETWORKS: AN EMPIRICAL STUDY](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08760.pdf)

> We further establish that factors associated with poor generalization
> – such as full-batch training or using random labels – correspond to lower
> robustness, while factors associated with good generalization – such as data
> augmentation and ReLU non-linearities – give rise to more robust functions.

From my experience you could try this things:

- Reduce Batch Size. "It is well known that too large of a batch size will lead to poor generalization"
- Use regularization. If you train a simple linear regression on a 0 mean data the alpha value can't be zero unless if you use a regularization. The L1L2 regularization is very good.
- Use a non linear activation like relu.
- Choose one of this architecture Deep, Wide or Cross. For some data the correlation is more important than the data itself.

To measure the sensitive, you can change the learning rate, if the results are to much noise, is a bad sing.